# Safari popup appears and links to my app in appstore

Tags: safari, hyperlink, app-store

I have an app in the App Store.  I would like for my website to display a popup with a link to my app when users visit my site with an iPad or iPhone.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

As of iOS 6 mobile safari will insert a popup on top of the website for the application if you add :

`<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=XXXXXXXXXX, app-argument=foobar" />`

If the id matches a application in the appstore the popup contains the icon of the application, the name of the developer, wether it is installed or not and a button to either open or install it.

Comment: And it's called Smart App Banners.

Comment: Hey, can you please remind me how this same functionality is called for Android? Thanks for above - exactly was I was also looking for.